# Reference request: A book to explain the definition $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(t)-f(t_n)}{t-t_n}$ showing a function is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have a function $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$ where I is an interval in $\mathbb{R}$.

I have two sequences $t$ and $t_n$.

I am told that if $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(t)-f(t_n)}{t-t_n}$$  exists, then the function $f$ is continuous.

Is there a book which explains this definition?

In the books I have seen such as Walter Rudin "principles of mathematics", the differentiability of a function is only examined at a point rather than the whole function.

The context in which I am looking at it is that I am using that definition to prove that a certain function is not differentiable.

Comment: what do you mean when you call $t$ "a sequence"?

Comment: This is not true as stated. For example, let $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ for $x \neq 0$, and $f(0) = 0$. Choose $t=0$ and $t_n = 1/(2\pi n)$. Then $f(t) - f(t_n) = 0$ for every $n$, so the limit exists, but $f$ is not continuous at $0$. You need a stronger hypothesis, namely that $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(t) - f(t_n)}{t-t_n}$$exists for **every** sequence $t_n$ converging to $t$ (with $t_n \neq t$).

Comment: @Bungo, a minor quibble:  As your counterexample demonstrates, you definitely need *some* stronger hypothesis, but the specific one you name, while *sufficient*, isn't, strictly speaking, *necessary*.

Comment: @BarryCipra Good point, certainly differentiability is not necessary for continuity. But I'm guessing that the above is what was intended here. Is there another generally applicable but less strict criterion involving limits of the difference quotient which suffices to imply continuity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that you don't have two sequences; rather, fixing $t$ in $I$, we take $t_n$ to be an arbitrary sequence converging to $t$ (and for technical reasons $t_n \neq t$ for all $n$). In this case, the existence of the given limit is equivalent to the existence of the derivative $f'$ at the point $t$. If the limit exists, then we see \begin{align*} \lim_{n\to\infty} \lvert f(t) - f(t_n) \rvert &= \lim_{n\to\infty} \lvert t -t_n \rvert \frac{\lvert f(t) - f(t_n) \rvert}{\lvert t - t_n \rvert}\\
&= \left( \lim_{n\to\infty} \lvert t -t_n \rvert\right) \left(\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\lvert f(t) - f(t_n) \rvert}{\lvert t - t_n \rvert}\right) = 0 \cdot \lvert f'(t) \rvert = 0.
\end{align*} Thus whenever $t_n \to t$, we have $f(t_n) \to f(t)$ which implies continuity of $f$ at $t$ by the sequential criterion theorem.

This is *not* a definition of continuity; indeed a function may be continuous and the given limit may fail to exist. However, existence of the limit implies the continuity of $f$.

Comment: Have you got a book which would contain this? I need a reference for my project

Comment: @Aljabra No book would contain this as a "definition of continuity" as you request since it is not a definition of continuity. However, as a definition of the derivative, check Rudin chapter 5 (?)

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are looking to investigate. Rudin's PMA certainly has a discussion of results like this (differentiability implies continuity, e.g.) and related concepts. I also don't quite understand what you mean by 'the differentiability of a function is only examined at a point rather than the whole function'. This is because differentiability is a local property so it has to be defined at points. A function is generally called 'differentiable' if it is differentiable at every point in its domain.

Comment: @Bungo Yes of course! Thanks for the edit, fixing it now.